# Traduzir «silly», sem maldade

Tags: tradução-inglês, tradução, palavra-para-ideia

Em inglês podemos usar a palavra «silly» em varias situações para dizer, com menos maldade, coisas que, com outras palavras, seriam mais ofensivas: que alguém está, ou as suas ações ou ideias são doidas, estúpidas, frívolas, levianas, hiperativas, etc. Quer dizer, é uma palavra que geralmente fala mal, ou rejeita, mas também geralmente sem maldade. É usualmente utilizado com crianças ou pessoas próximas.

Há uma boa maneira de expressar o mesmo em português? Pode ser qualquer classe gramatical.

Literalmente, «silly» pode descrever o comportamento de um palhaço num circo. Mas acho que, fora do circo, «palhaçaria» tende a ser dito com maldade ou raiva.

Mais exemplos:

> The boy is making **silly** faces.

> The kids are feeling very **silly**.

> — I feel like nobody enjoyed my party.
>
> — That's **silly**, everyone had a great time!

> That was a **silly** thing to do. I hope you make a better decision next time.

Já sei que qualquer palavra pode ser ou não ofensiva, dependendo do contexto interpessoal e do tom de voz. Mas, quais palavras portuguesas, com significados parecidos com «silly», tendem a ser *menos* ofensivas?

Nos dicionários, encontrei *bobo*, *tolo*, e *tonto*, mas não sei que gravidade estas palavras tem.

Comment: Eu vi algumas pessoas usando silly como um "elogio" de certa forma, eu amo tubarões e em alguns videos fofos sobre eles pessoas comentam "so silly" mas não como algo ruim, e sim como se fosse "tão fofo" ou algo parecido, há alguma explicação para isso?

Comment: @Star Complementei minha resposta para responder à sua questão.

Comment: Um truque para suavizar o efeito depreciativo das palavras é colocá-las no diminutivo, então “bobinho”, “tolinho” seriam bons equivalentes genéricos de _silly,_ embora eu concorde que provavelmente é melhor considerar a frase como um todo e usar traduções diferentes em contextos diferentes, como na resposta de @stafusa.

Comment: Ótimo ponto, @Wtrmute, obrigado. Vou incluir em minha resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você achou estava correto: em pt-BR, "tolo" e "bobo" podem ser boas traduções, e "tonto" em alguns casos também (e ANeves apresenta uma lista similar para o pt-PT em [sua resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8079/2764)).

Mas vale notar que algumas das expressões dadas como exemplo eu traduziria — livremente — com outras palavras:

- *The boy is making silly faces.*
  O menino está fazendo caretas.
- *The kids are feeling very silly.*
  As crianças estão muito brincalhonas.
- *— I feel like nobody enjoyed my party.

  — That's silly, everyone had a great time!*
  – Tenho a impressão de que ninguém curtiu a minha festa.
  – Bobagem, todo mundo se divertiu um monte!
- *That was a silly thing to do. I hope you make a better decision next time.*
  O que você fez foi bobagem. Espero que você tome uma decisão melhor da próxima vez.

Quanto ao comentário de Star:

> Eu vi algumas pessoas usando silly como um "elogio" de certa forma, eu amo tubarões e em alguns videos fofos sobre eles pessoas comentam "so silly" mas não como algo ruim, e sim como se fosse "tão fofo" ou algo parecido, há alguma explicação para isso?

A interpretação oferecida pelo contexto está correta e "fofo" ou "gracinha" são possíveis traduções, assim como as mencionadas por Wtrmute, os diminutivos "tolinho" e "bobinho".

Da mesma forma como em português, o significado de um "Você é tão bobo." pode depender muito do tom de voz, e o [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Silly) inclui significados para "*silly*" como *flirty* ("de paquera", "provocador"), e "[estupidamente] adorável" — que provavelmente se aplica aos tubarões no contexto descrito.

Answer (score 4):

Em pt-PT, "tolo" e "tonto" correspondem bem a *silly*.

Tecnicamente são palavras de conotação negativa, mas são depois usadas com carinho: quando alguém diz ao seu amor "oh, que tolo" ou "oh, que tolinho" em resposta a uma brincadeira; ou igualmente a uma criança.

E a palavra *silly* é usada da mesma forma em inglês.

> O rapaz está a fazer caretas tolas.

> — Acho que ninguém gostou da minha festa.
> — Que tolice, toda a gente se divertiu imenso!

Não sei bem como traduzir estas duas para português usando sinónimos portugueses para *silly*:

> The kids are feeling very silly.

> That was a silly thing to do. I hope you make a better decision next time.

---

*Acho* que bobo tem o mesmo sentido, mas a palavra não é usada com esse sentido em Portugal; só com o sentido de "palhaço".